# transformed image inside div

Tags: html, css

I trying put tranformed image inside div with specific dimension with using "img src" approach. As a result, there has to be inside red bordered div only transformed cut of image. But as You see image overlapping outside... What I misssing? Thanks

css>

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    transform: scale(2.5);
    transform-origin: 0 0;
}

.portrait {
    height: 125px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 2px red solid;
}
```

html>

```
<div class="portrait">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkF9Q.jpg">
</div>
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o5nbnmbe/)

Comment: change `max-width` into `width`

Comment: You only want to be able to see what is inside the div? Or you want the image to fit inside the div?

Answer (score 3):

You Are Only missing `overflow: hidden;` in `div` element

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  transform: scale(2.5);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}

.portrait {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 125px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 2px red solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="portrait">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkF9Q.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As what I understood you want `image` to be inside of assigned `height and width` of `parent div`, if so then in those cases add `overflow:hidden` to `parent div`, thus this stop overflowing of `child element`.

> The overflow property specifies whether to clip content, render
>   scrollbars or just display content when it overflows its block level
>   container.

```css
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    transform: scale(2.5);
    transform-origin: 0 0;
}

.portrait {
    height: 125px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 2px red solid;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="portrait">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkF9Q.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use overflow: hidden inside the portrait:

```
.portrait {
  height: 125px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 2px red solid;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

With this attribute the content is clipped and no scrollbars are provided when it is bigger than the container.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i guess i understood. You should do:

```
img {
    width: 100%; // Edited
    height: auto; // Edited
    display:block; // Edited
    transform: scale(2.5);
    transform-origin: 0 0;
}

.portrait {
    height: 125px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 2px red solid;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```